# Wrap all elements up until :nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time figuring this out, but I am sure it is simple.

I know that I have to use `:nth-child` to count every set of elements I want to wrap.  I am wondering how I would count to `:nth-child` and wrap all the previous elements including the `:nth-child` in a div for each set of elements that match `:nth-child`.  I am assuming there is an `.each()` involved.

The code would be laid out like so:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<h3>Heading</h3>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>

<h3>Heading</h3>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>


<h3>Heading</h3>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>


<h3>Heading</h3>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

**Update**  Tried this piece of code and it seems to give me the desired results, but stops at 16.

```
  $(".wrapper").each( function () {
$(this).children(":lt(16)").wrapAll("<div></div>")
});
```

Comment: Please show some code. Preferably HTML, with the elements you want to wrap marked.

Comment: Also, take a look at [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Might need to use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) in a loop to go back from the `:nth-child`

Comment: The question is still ambiguous - Is that the code you have, or the code you want? If it's either, what are you wanting or what are you starting with? And best of all, what have you tried?

Comment: @ahren this is the code I am starting with.  I have tried an `.each()` function to loop through all of the children and add a class every `nth`, but I can't seem to figure out how to select all of the previous elements that come before `nth`.

Comment: So which elements are you trying to wrap?

Comment: Every `nth` and it's previous elements, in my case, every 16 elements.

Comment: Every 16 elements? Or every 16 `a` elements?

Comment: doh! you updated while I was submitting answer, lol, fixing my answer to match your update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.each()` function has a built in `index` - so we can use that to our advantage to select every 16 elements.

```
$("div.wrapper").children().each(function(i){
    if(i % 16 == 0 && i != 0){
        // We get the elements we need to wrap, but they're going to be in reverse order (thanks to .prevAll())
        var elementsToWrap = $(this).prevAll().not('.wrap2');
        var temp = [];
        for(var j=0; j < elementsToWrap.size(); j++){
            // Reverse the objects selected by placing them in a temporary array.
            temp[(elementsToWrap.size()-1) - j] = elementsToWrap.eq(j)[0];
        }
        // Wrap the array back into a jQuery object, then use .wrapAll() to add a div around them
        $(temp).wrapAll('<div class="wrap2" />');
    }
});
```

​
**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/CRz7E/1/

If you wanted to wrap each element separately - instead of as a group, then you don't need to reverse the selection, and you could just use `.wrap()`

Comment: kewl, I was busy fixing son lunch and couldn't get my answer updated quick enough, this looks good, +1

Comment: This works how I described it.  How do I wrap the remaining items in a div?

Comment: After the `.each()` you could do another selection. `$("div.wrapper").children().not('.wrap2').wrapAll('<div class="not-a-full-set wrap2" />');`

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several ways, thought the easiest I can think of uses [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
I'll simply show you an easy example, and perhaps you can modify your question some for a more specific answer.

Suppose your HTML is something simple like the following:

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .goober {
            background: #ffa;
            color: #696969;
        }
    </style>

    <div>1</div>
    <p>1</p>
    <div>2</div>
    <p>2</p>
    <div>3</div>
    <p>3</p>
    <div>4</div>
    <p>4</p>​
</body>
```

And say you wanted to wrap all the p elements in a div with the class "goober".  All of course except the *LAST* one of course.

Then you can jQuery it up as follows:

```
$(function() {
    // here i use .filter and in the return i recall the same jQuery array 
    // object that i'm filtering in order to compare the index value to 
    // its length
    $("p").filter(function(i) { 
        return i != $("p").length-1; 
    }).wrap('<div class="goober" />'); // then of course our wrapper
});​
```

jQuery methods used:

- .filter = http://api.jquery.com/filter/
- .length = http://api.jquery.com/length/
- .wrap = http://api.jquery.com/wrap/